# Constructing Pandas DataFrame from Nested Dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary with three layers, the bottom layer being a mixture of dictionaries and values and want to convert it into a dataframe with keys from the last layer as column names and keys from the first layer as ids.

```
dict = {"id1": {"att_1": 1,
                "att_2": {"att2_1": "value1",
                          "att2_2": "value2"}},
        "id2": {"att_1": 2,
                "att_2": {"att2_1": "value3",
                "att2_2": "value4"}}
}
```

I tried around a little bit with the 'pandas.DataFrame.from_dict()' function:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict({(i): x_dict[i][j] for i in x_dict.keys() for j in x_dict[i].keys()}, orient='index')
```

However, the output I am getting lost all the values from the second layer(att1):

```
     att2_1  att2_2
id1  value1  value2
id2  value3  value4
```

Is there a better way to approach this or how could I fix my current attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can define a function to traverse and find all attributes by dfs, as folow:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def convert(node):
    t = defaultdict(list)
    def dfs(node):
            for k, v in node.items():
                if isinstance(v, dict):
                    dfs(v)
                else:
                    t[k].append(v)
    dfs(node)
    return t
```

now you can simply create your dataframe (di as your main dictionary):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(convert(di))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work, but I havent accounted for the fact that third level keys can have the same name as second level keys, so they get stored in the same list in the defaultdict now. How could I adapt your code to avoid this?

Comment: you can add the key depth as well as an info, every time you go one further depth in dfs, you could as well store the depth and add in your key, like att2_1_depth2 (something) or something properly named. other wise you can not have same key in the dic in two place (it is called dictionary). Then accept as answer it solved your question.

Answer (score 0):

from: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFaaq.png)

i think you need multiIndex columns and get lists instead inner dicts

```
new_dict = {(outerKey, innerKey): values for outerKey, innerDict in dict_.items() for innerKey, values in innerDict.items()}
pd.DataFrame(new_dict)
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFaaq.png)